# How to apply a function across multiple groups and loop over multiple columns

Tags: function, for-loop, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

In R, I'm trying to apply a custom function across groupings, for multiple columns. Then, I want to add to my dataframe new columns that contain the output data.

Here are dummy data:

```
data <- data.frame(id = seq(1, 100, by = 1),
                     sex = sample(c('M', 'F'), 100, replace = TRUE),
                     age_class = sample(c('A', 'S'), 100, replace = TRUE), # A = adult, S = subadult
                     weight = sample(80:600, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     offspring = sample(c('Y','N'), 100, replace = TRUE),
                     albumin = rnorm(100, 5, 2),
                     cortisol = rnorm(100, 30, 12),
                     calcium = rnorm(100, 0.3, 0.005),
                     globulin = rnorm(100, 1.9, 0.3),
                     insulin = rnorm(100, 3, 0.13))
```

Here is the function I made - it calculates modified z-scores, given column i in a data frame.

```
mod.zscore <- function(df, i) {
  vec <- df[[i]]
  median.vec <- median(vec, na.rm = TRUE)
  absolute.diff <- abs(vec - median.vec)
  MAD <- median(absolute.diff, na.rm = TRUE)
  mod.z <- (0.6745 * (vec - median.vec)) / MAD
  return(mod.z)
}
```

The function call looks like:

```
mod.zscore(data, 'albumin')
```

I want the function to apply to groupings by age class and sex, so that the function calculates z-scores for adult-male,  adult-female, subadult-male, and subadult-female groups separately. I think I will need to have a group_by call somewhere in there.

```
data %>% group_by(age_class, sex)
### execute things
ungroup()
```

I want to apply the function to columns albumin:insulin and then create new columns to add to my dataset that contain the output data. The new column names should be albumin_zscore, cortisol_zscore, calcium_zscore, globulin_zscore, and insulin_zscore.

I'm stuck on how to get all of these steps working at once - grouping the data, getting my function to loop over i columns, and create new columns to add to my data frame that follow the syntax pattern of i_zscore.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reframe` or if you have an older dplyr version, `summarize`

reframe will take some column data and output a dataframe and it works with `dplyr`'s other functions like group by.

With some modification to your function, we do:

```
mod.zscore <- function(dat) {
  vec <- dat
  median.vec <- median(vec, na.rm = TRUE)
  absolute.diff <- abs(vec - median.vec)
  MAD <- median(absolute.diff, na.rm = TRUE)
  mod.z <- (0.6745 * (vec - median.vec)) / MAD
  
  return(mod.z)
}
```

```
data |> 
   group_by(sex, age_class) |> 
   reframe(across(albumin:insulin, mod.zscore, .names = "{.col}_{'zscore'}"))
```

If you have an older dplyr version you might have to call `ungroup` after

```
 sex   age_class albumin_zscore cortisol_zscore calcium_zscore globulin_zscore insulin_zscore
   <chr> <chr>              <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 F     A               -0.602            1.55            0.522           0.158         1.16  
 2 F     A                0.113           -0.414          -0.922           0.727        -0.0225
 3 F     A               -1.03             1.01            0.767          -1.19         -3.49  
 4 F     A               -1.57            -0.437           0.230           0.209         0.388 
 5 F     A                0.648           -0.812          -1.34           -0.999         0.583 
 6 F     A               -0.00657          0.718           0.411           0.885        -0.701 
 7 F     A               -0.309           -0.379          -0.350           0.535        -0.743 
 8 F     A                0.104            0.642          -0.683          -0.173        -2.08  
 9 F     A                0.359            0.0863          0.950          -1.66          0.555 
10 F     A               -0.983            0.274           1.07           -1.04          0.648
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Just James . I used your code with mutate() instead of reframe () to keep the original rows too.
In my original question I forgot to add a variable season, with two factors (spring, autumn). Edited the question now. I am also trying to modify this